# The equivalent of GetValue in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, thinkscript

Thinkorswim has a function called GetValue which "Returns the value of data with the specified dynamic offset".

https://tlc.thinkorswim.com/center/reference/thinkScript/Functions/Others/GetValue.html

Is there an equivalent function in Pine Script for tradingview that does the same thing?

Comment: I guess you can achieve that by using [History Referencing Operator](https://www.tradingview.com/wiki/Operators#History_Referencing_Operator_.28Square_Brackets_.5B.5D.29). Tell us what you want to do and then we might help you. Maybe there are other ways..

Answer (score 0):

I gues can use the far function or the valuewhen function. Tell us what you want to do and then we might help you. Maybe there are other ways

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and thats the security function

For instance if you want to get the close of the candle on 1Hr time frame,

You would call

`security(syminfo.tickerid, '60', close)`